# how to check Json Norm value in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, compare

I have JSON object to hold the selected item from grid UI. I have validation rule where the selected items must be in the same NORM all 1s or 2s

```
selectedAssessments=[{"id":"babe42c3-13b8-e711-80c7-0050568f1fad","checked":true,"norm":1},{"id":"86f893e1-37b8-e711-80c7-0050568f1fad","checked":true,"norm":1}];


    if(selectedAssessments.some(item => ( !(item.norm === 1) ||!(item.norm ===2))))
    {
       alert('value must  the same norms.');
       break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observation of your code:**

- Your condition is a little confused, what you need to do is: `item.norm !== 1 && item.norm !== 2`.

**Now let's execute the code:**

```js
var selectedAssessments = [{
  "id": "babe42c3-13b8-e711-80c7-0050568f1fad",
  "checked": true,
  "norm": 1
}, {
  "id": "86f893e1-37b8-e711-80c7-0050568f1fad",
  "checked": true,
  "norm": 1
}];


if ( selectedAssessments.some(item => item.norm !== 1 && item.norm !== 2) )  {
  alert('value must  the same norms.');
} else {
  console.log("Everything looks good!");
}
```

Comment: I have small problem with condition if I change the norm to 2 and become 1 and 2 that should give me   alert('value must  the same norms.'); but it give me console.log("Everything looks good!");

Answer (score 0):

You can run the filter command on the array. This will return a new array that past the filter you set. If both arrays are of the same length then your test completed ok.